# How to override Bootstrap mixin without modifying the actual source code?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, mixins

I'm using Bootstrap 4 and I would like to change default style of button hover and active states. Those can't be changed with variables because those are hard coded in Sass mixins. For example:

```
@mixin button-variant($color, $background, $border) {
  $active-background: darken($background, 10%);
  $active-border: darken($border, 12%);
  ...
```

In order to get the style I want, I need to change darken to lighten and then change percents.

I could modify source code but it doesn't sound like a good solution for maintenance. I could also override those values with my custom css file included after Bootstrap but then I basically need to copy-paste whole button source from Bootstrap and modify it. Because there is lot of button variants, there will be lot of overrides which would be unnecessary in case of I can include changes to Bootstrap css.

Best solution would be to override whole button-variant mixin in Bootstrap before compilation so that in compiled Bootstrap file there is only css I want. What would be the best way to do that?

Comment: You should be able to include your own separate file, rewriting that mixin. If it's included after bootstrap's, the compiler should user your mixin instead.

Answer (score 10):

Override the mixin by including your own version after it before compiling.

/scss/site.scss

```
// libraries
@import 'libraries/bootstrap/bootstrap';

// your custom sass files
@import 'overrides/bootstrap/mixins';
```

/scss/overrides/bootstrap/mixins.scss

```
@mixin button-variant($color, $background, $border) {
  $active-background: darken($background, 10%);
  $active-border: darken($border, 12%);
  ...
```

Comment: I tried that approach but started to get errors: Undefined variable: "$..." so I thought that approach is not working. I think I shouldn't have to include Bootstrap variables again. Maybe there is something else wrong, I'll try again.

Comment: Be sure you're including bootstrap in your main scss file, and that everything compiles together @m5seppal

Comment: I got this working but it seems that it's not any better than including your own custom style after Bootstrap. In cause of overriding Bootstrap variables, only my own style does have effect because of Bootstrap variables have !default. But if I override mixins, initial mixin is still compiled and there will be a lot of duplicate code.

So far best approach I've been able to think is to comment out original source include from main file and include your own customized version instead.
//@import "buttons";
@import "overrides/buttons";

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to modify existing bootstrap files.

Cleanest solution, working for me, is to include all base bootstrap imports in my own *bootstrap-custom.scss* file and swap original *_mixins.scss* file with my own, again including all original mixins with exception of my custom *_buttons.scss*.

Comment: To go into a little more detail for anyone who this isn't clear enough. I'd import `functions`, `variables`, `utilities` and `mixins`, then follow with your own mixins (if you have everything in one file, like me, otherwise just import your mixin file) and then import all the other files that are imported if you'd import bootstrap directly. Afterward, do **not** import the bootstrap scss or it will generate all the css twice.

Answer (score 3):

Overwriting the bootstrap mixins after using them doesn't seem to work - like this issue describes:
https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/240

So I ended up with modifying the bootstrap main source-file. This is no beautiful solution, but needed since the order is that important. In my case it looks like this ('bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap'):

```
/*!
 * Bootstrap v3.3.7
 * Copyright 2011-2016 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT
 */

// Core variables and mixins
@import "own_variables";
@import "bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/variables";
@import "bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins";
@import "own_mixins";

// ... rest of bootstrap includes which use the mixins to create classes
```

Comment: helpful issue link

Answer (score 3):

To overwrite a mixin, The easiest and cleanest way is:

1. copy the file bootstrap.scss in your own custom folder:

   ```
   @import "functions";
   @import "variables";
   @import "mixins";
   @import "root";
   etc...
   ```
2. Adapt the files paths and add you own file in the list

   ```
   @import "../../bootstrap-4.4.1-dist/scss/functions";
   @import "../../bootstrap-4.4.1-dist/scss/variables";
   @import "../../bootstrap-4.4.1-dist/scss/mixins";
   @import "bs-mixins";  <--- put your customized mixins file after the bootstrap mixins
   @import "../../bootstrap-4.4.1-dist/scss/root";
   etc...
   ```

It makes sense to have all the needed bootstrap features listed together here. It is also the right place to make some cleanup if you don't need all features, in order the reduce the css footprint.