# How to Modify Bootstrap 4 Mixins without Editing Core Files

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4, mixins, scss-mixins

So basically, I'm trying to modify the button-variant mixin in bootstrap 4. The core file where the code for this resides is bootstrap\scss\mixins, and the filename is _buttons.scss. In my custom.scss, I have the following code:

```
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

I would want to keep the mixin name the same and not override it using a different name because it's being used in the file node_modules\bootstrap\scss_buttons.scss in the following code that generates all buttons based on the colors available:

```
@each $color, $value in $theme-colors {
.btn-#{$color} {
@include button-variant($value, $value);
}
}
```

What happens is that when the new modified mixin code is added below importing bootstrap in custom.scss, it does not have any effect as the imported bootstrap gets compiled after that code and the default button css gets compiled. Whereas, when the modified mixin code is added after importing bootstrap in custom.scss, there is duplication of buttons in the compiled .css file.

How would one go about modifying the code in a mixin without editing the core bootstrap files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to override Bootstrap mixin without modifying the actual source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39707334/how-to-override-bootstrap-mixin-without-modifying-the-actual-source-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should import Bootstrap's SCSS files separately instead of the whole pack, and you should import your own mixins after Bootstrap's `_mixins.scss`. This way you can override them before Bootstrap's `_buttons.scss` would use them:

```
@import "bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "bootstrap/scss/mixins";

@import "my-custom-mixins";

// rest of Bootstrap imports (see bootstrap.scss):
@import "bootstrap/scss/root";
@import "bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "bootstrap/scss/type";
@import "bootstrap/scss/images";
@import "bootstrap/scss/code";
@import "bootstrap/scss/grid";
@import "bootstrap/scss/tables";
@import "bootstrap/scss/forms";
@import "bootstrap/scss/buttons";
@import "my-custom-buttons";
@import "bootstrap/scss/transitions";
@import "bootstrap/scss/dropdown";
@import "bootstrap/scss/button-group";
@import "bootstrap/scss/input-group";
@import "bootstrap/scss/custom-forms";
@import "bootstrap/scss/nav";
@import "bootstrap/scss/navbar";
@import "bootstrap/scss/card";
@import "bootstrap/scss/breadcrumb";
@import "bootstrap/scss/pagination";
@import "bootstrap/scss/badge";
@import "bootstrap/scss/jumbotron";
@import "bootstrap/scss/alert";
@import "bootstrap/scss/progress";
@import "bootstrap/scss/media";
@import "bootstrap/scss/list-group";
@import "bootstrap/scss/close";
@import "bootstrap/scss/toasts";
@import "bootstrap/scss/modal";
@import "bootstrap/scss/tooltip";
@import "bootstrap/scss/popover";
@import "bootstrap/scss/carousel";
@import "bootstrap/scss/spinners";
@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities";
@import "bootstrap/scss/print";
```

Comment: Will the import of _my-custom-buttons.scss have to be after the definition of the new modified mixin button-variant?

Also, curious as to what would happen if going forward, bootstrap come out with a new updated _buttons.scss file. The edits would be lost. Is that a compromise that is inevitable at this point?

Comment: My original idea is to copy Bootstrap's `_buttons.scss` into your project folder as `_my-custom-buttons.scss` and modify what you want there. And yes, when you upgrade Bootstrap, you have to repeat the process again. **But!** I have just found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39707334/how-to-override-bootstrap-mixin-without-modifying-the-actual-source-code) and it seems that you can do this a lot easier. Just include your custom mixins after Bootstrap's `_mixins.scss`, so you can override them before Bootstrap's `_buttons.scss` would use them. Please see my edited answer.